# What is actually being maximized in the fitting of a logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, logit

When a logistic regression is being fit to a set of data, what is the *actual* value that is being maximized? What I mean is, as the coefficients are being determined, what criterion is being used to determine the "best fitting model"?

Is it: the number of cases that are correctly classified based on the calculated Y value for each case?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean other than maximizing the likelihood?

Comment: I guess I'm wondering exactly what likelihood is being maximized.

Comment: The likelihood of observing the given data, given values of the parameters. L(X | theta). just google "logistic regression maximum likelihood estimator" and you get a ton of results, such as this [one](https://neos-guide.org/content/logit)

Comment: What is being compared? Is it the observed probabilities vs. the predicted probabilities, on a case by case basis?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=logistic+likelihood

Comment: Thanks for the link. As someone who isn't all that familiar with formulas, can you give me the coles notes version of the answer to my question?

Comment: You are estimating the probability of $Y=1$ with a non-linear (sigmoid) formula. So you can just maximize the MLE of a Bernoulli rv, i.e. $p^y\,(1-p)^{1-y}$, keeping in mind that eventually, you have to replace $p$ with $\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}.$

Comment: I think that maybe I'm not being clear in my question (or I'm just misinterpreting the answers!).

In the process of maximizing the logistic regression, is the formula:

1) creating a probability that each case is a 0 or 1, given the predictors, and then checking that against their known categories, and altering the coefficients to maximize correct classification?

or

2) checking predicted probabilities against known probabilities, and minimizing the differences somehow

Comment: @Dave The first thing.  The logistic regression works with the estimated probabilities, and the true values.